# SwiftUI gesture(DragGesture) Keeps getting stuck

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mobile-development

long time reader first time writer here so sorry if I mess up. Im' having issue with the gesture in SwiftUI it keeps getting stuck, it does move a little but then stops. I have also noticed that when the position of the card is stuck, even when I change its position on the array it maintains its weird stuck position. I had initially tested it and it worked fine. Initially was having issues with forEach not re rendering and think I have fixed that.

My ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var villagers: [VillagerCard] = getJSONTest(from: "data", count: 5)
    @State var villagersLiked: [VillagerCard] = []

    func addVillagerToLiked (villager: VillagerCard) {
        print("LIKED")
        if let index = villagers.firstIndex(of: villager) {
            let removedVillager = villagers.remove(at: index)
            villagersLiked.append(removedVillager)
        }
    }

    func addVillagerToBack (villager: VillagerCard) {
        print("DISLIKED")
        if let index = villagers.firstIndex(of: villager) {
            let removedVillager = villagers.remove(at: index)
            villagers.append(removedVillager)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text("Discover")
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                    .font(.system(size: 45))
                ZStack {
                    ForEach(villagers, id: \.id) { villager in
                        Card(data: villager, addVillagerToLiked: addVillagerToLiked, addVillagerToBack: addVillagerToBack)
                    }
                }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                HStack {
                    Button {
                        villagers.append(villagers.remove(at: 0))
                    } label: {
                        ZStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRad)
                                .frame(width: geo.size.width / 3, height: 50)
                                .foregroundColor(Color("card-background"))
                            Image(systemName: "arrowshape.turn.up.backward.fill")
                                .font(.system(size: 25))
                        }
                    }
                }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                    Spacer()
                }
                    .font(.system(size: 25))
                    .padding(10)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .background(Color("card-background"))
                    .cornerRadius(cornerRad)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .padding(.top, 10)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Card

```
var cornerRad: CGFloat = 30

struct Card: View {
    @State var data: VillagerCard
    var addVillagerToLiked: (VillagerCard) -> Void
    var addVillagerToBack: (VillagerCard) -> Void

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                Color("card-background")
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                    ZStack {
                        Color("card-img-background")
                        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: data.villager.poster)) { image in
                            image
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 40)
                                .padding(.top, 40)
                        } placeholder: {
                            ProgressView()
                        }
                    }
                        .background(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(cornerRad)
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: (geo.size.height * 4) / 5)
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text("\(data.villager.name)")
                                .font(.system(size: 40))
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                            Image(systemName: "person")
                                .font(.system(size: 30))
                        }
                        Text("\(data.villager.personality)")
                            .font(.system(size: 20))
                    }
                        .frame(
                        minWidth: 0,
                        maxWidth: .infinity,
                        minHeight: 0,
                        maxHeight: .infinity,
                        alignment: .topLeading
                    )
                        .padding(.horizontal, 25)
                        .padding(.vertical, 10)
                        .background(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(cornerRad - 10)
                        .padding(10)
//                        .frame(height: geo.size.height / 5, alignment: .topLeading)
                }
            }
                .cornerRadius(cornerRad)
                .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .onChanged({ value in
                    if value.translation.width > 0 {
                        // swiping to the right and it goes past some value
                        if value.translation.width > 30 {
                            data.update(degreeTo: 12, valueTo: value.translation.width)
                        }
                        // swiping to the right and it dosent go past some value
                            else {
                            print("INCHANGED RIGHT ELSE")
                            data.update(degreeTo: 0, valueTo: value.translation.width)
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        // swiping to the left and it goes past some value
                        if value.translation.width < -30 {
                            data.update(degreeTo: -12, valueTo: value.translation.width)
                        }
                        // swiping to the left and it dosent go past some value
                            else {
                            print("INCHANGED LEFT ELSE")
                            data.update(degreeTo: 0, valueTo: value.translation.width)
                        }
                    }
                })
                    .onEnded({ value in
                    if data.value > 0 {
                        // after a certain data.value adds card to "like"
                        if data.value > geo.size.width / 4 {
                            data.update(degreeTo: 0, valueTo: 500)
                            addVillagerToLiked(data)
                        }
                        else {
                            data.update(degreeTo: 0, valueTo: 0)
                        }
                    }
                    else if data.value < 0 {
                        // after a certain data.value adds card to "dislike"
                        if -data.value > geo.size.width / 4 {
                            data.update(degreeTo: 0, valueTo: -500)
                            addVillagerToBack(data)
                        }
                        else {
                            data.update(degreeTo: 0, valueTo: 0)
                        }
                    }
                }))
                .offset(x: data.value)
                .scaleEffect(abs(data.value) > 80 ? 0.9 : 1)
                .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: data.degree))
                .animation(.spring(response: 0.25), value: data.value)
        }
    }
}
```

and the Helper

```
class VillagerData: Codable {
    let poster: String
    let name: String
    let species: String
    let gender: String
    let personality: String
    let birthday: String
    let catchphrase: String

    init(poster: String, name: String, species: String, gender: String, personality: String, birthday: String, catchphrase: String) {
        self.poster = poster
        self.name = name
        self.species = species
        self.gender = gender
        self.personality = personality
        self.birthday = birthday
        self.catchphrase = catchphrase
    }
}

struct VillagerCard: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var villager: VillagerData
    var degree: CGFloat = .zero
    var value: CGFloat = .zero

    static func == (lhs: VillagerCard, rhs: VillagerCard) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }

    mutating func update(degreeTo newDegree: CGFloat, valueTo newValue: CGFloat) {
        degree = newDegree
        value = newValue
    }
}

func readLocalJSONFile(forName name: String) -> Data? {
    do {
        if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "json") {
            let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
            return data
        }
    } catch {
        print("error: \(error)")
    }
    return nil
}

func getJSONData (from file: String) -> Data? {
    guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file, ofType: "json") else {
        return nil
    }
    do {
        let fileContents = try String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: .utf8)
        guard let jsonData = fileContents.data(using: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }
        return jsonData
    } catch {
        print("error: \(error)")
    }
    return nil
}

func getJSON (from file: String) -> [VillagerCard] {
    do {
        var res: [VillagerCard] = []
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let villagerList = try decoder.decode([VillagerData].self, from: getJSONData(from: file)!)
        villagerList.forEach { villagerData in
            res.append(VillagerCard(villager: villagerData, degree: .zero, value: .zero))
        }
        return res
    } catch {
        print("error: \(error)")
        return []
    }
}

func getJSONTest (from file: String, count num: Int) -> [VillagerCard] {
    do {
        var res: [VillagerCard] = []
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let villagerList = try decoder.decode([VillagerData].self, from: getJSONData(from: file)!)
        villagerList.forEach { villagerData in
            res.append(VillagerCard(villager: villagerData, degree: .zero, value: .zero))
        }
        return Array(res[0 ..< 5])
    } catch {
        print("error: \(error)")
        return []
    }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).